# How to retain UITextField text when navigating to different view controller and returning back?

Tags: ios

The first view controller has number of textfield along with three button where each button is  pushed to different view controller. The case is same for the other view controllers too. I want to retain the textfield values entered remains same, irrespective of navigating from one view controller to others in all view ?

Comment: How did you return back to the parent (previous) controller currently?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. You have to know when your controllers are deallocated. After deallocation you cannot restore the values, but if you stored the values in i.e. in NSUserDefaults, when the controller deallocates, then you can restore.

Normally, if another viewController is pushed, the last one is hold in memory, to get back smoothly. Forward pushing is always initializing a new controller, for which you have to think about how to store the old values (i.e. NSUserDefaults or implementing nscoding)

Answer (score 0):

Store the buttons (or NSStrings containing the text) as ivars (instance variables) within your first controller. As long as you aren't getting rid of that controller and recreating it, they should persist.